# java version in not match for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I had java version 8 previous and my eclipse worked just fine. But now I have java version 7 and I can't open eclipse on my computer. What should I do? please help.

[image: Error]

[image]

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: Java 8 or higher is required to run newer version of Eclipse. You can download it from [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/). Either install Java on your system or unzip it into `jre` subfolder of your Eclipse installation directory. To run Eclipse only a JRE is required, but to have the source code of the Java system library a JDK is required.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two options:

- Upgrade to Java version 8 (or newer).
- If you can't do that, downgrade to a version of eclipse that supports Java 7. [eclipse 4.5 (Mars)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.5_.28Mars.29) (or earlier as noted on the linked page), as of eclipse 4.6 (Neon) Java 8 is required.

I feel I should note that newer versions of Java (and eclipse) can still **target** Java 7 (and many earlier versions).

Comment: @NimeshGihan Worst choice if safety and performance matters to you.

Comment: There's no _"If you can't do that"_ here. You don't have to upgrade Java 7. You can have Java 8 or higher in addition to Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

> But now I have java version 7 and I can't open eclipse on my computer. What should I do?

Use versions that work together. When you for example look at your second screen shot, it says something like "requiredJavaVersion=1.8" or so.

In other words: you can't just come in and **run** eclipse with any version of java.

The other answer gives you the required details.

And a final note here: in case you tried to **start** eclipse with that older JVM in order to "allow" to ensure that eclipse won't allow "java 8" stuff in a project: that isn't the right way then. Instead: eclipse allows you to "define" JDKs to be used for your project. So you can easily tell eclipse: "I have a Java7 jdk sitting here, please use that for project X".

You do **not** need to run eclipse itself with a Java7 JVM in order to use a Java7 JDK for an eclipse project!

Answer (score 0):

There will be a file under the Eclipse installation directory named as eclipse.ini.
It will launch the eclipse for that specific jdf and you can change the path to your jdk7.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's really broad. How can he fix his problem with the `eclipse.ini`. How to "change" the path to his JDK. Can you elaborate to provide a complete solution.

Comment: Current versions of Eclipse will not run at all using Java 7 no matter what you do in the eclipse.ini. Java 8 or later is required.

Answer (score 0):

It depends basically on which version of the eclipse you have.

If you have `eclipse 4.6(Neon)` or the latest version, then you must need a newer JDK version of Java `(>=1.8 which you need to download).` Or If you want to roll back to an older version of Eclipse then consider downloading eclipse 4.5(Mars).

Or If you have an `eclipse version of 4.5(Mars)` or older then see in `eclipse.ini`
`-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion = 1.8 and change it to -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion = 1.7` which can be found in the folder containing `eclipse.exe` file.

Comment: For more details please see: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation